# making an immutable type mutable (consts and boost)

Tags: c++, boost, mutable

I am working on a feature for a codebase that I cannot change (save for what I'm writing) and there are some types here:

```
// Pointer to a mutable thingy
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Thingy>       MPtr;

// Pointer to an immutable thingy
typedef boost::shared_ptr<const Thingy> Ptr;
```

Now, I have an object of type MPtr that I need to assign to an object of type Ptr, but I can't (compiler tells me that there's no possible conversion). Using a const_cast doesn't seem to help either:

```
MPtr foo = const_cast<MPtr*>(moo);
```

I get an error saying it can't change the underlying type. Any ideas on how I can work around this issue?

Comment: How hacky are you willing to get? If you take the address of moo and then use a C style cast, and dereference that you should be good. MPtr foo = (Mptr)&moo;

Comment: Is `Thingy` a `typedef` or `#define`? Is `Thingy` the same string in both locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MPtr foo = boost::const_pointer_cast<Thingy>(moo);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion, however, I get an error saying:

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'boost::shared_ptr<T>'

Comment: @user1115716 Are both T types the same? What is the compiler output, not just the error?

Comment: I've worked around this issue by making a non-const version and shadowing the operations of the const version.